# UnexpectedNullableFound on left join

Tags: sql, scala, anorm

Hi I'm running into an issue where I get an UnexpectedNullableFound. The colum may return a null value, but I have this mapped (as below) as an Option, so should not cause an issue. This works for the other fields I take from this table. If I remove the 'pe.company AS admin_company' and related mappings from the code, I do not have any issues.

If the admin_company is null, I get this issue. If not, it executes fine.

I've read a number of related issues, but haven't found any solutions here.

Any ideas on this? Thanks

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: ColumnName(test_users.company,Some(admin_company))]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:265)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:191)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:179)
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:212)
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:94)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:266)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:262)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ColumnName(test_users.company,Some(admin_company))
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at anorm.SqlRequestError$class.toFailure(Anorm.scala:20)
    at anorm.UnexpectedNullableFound.toFailure(Anorm.scala:37)
    at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$asTry$2$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(Anorm.scala:303)
    at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$asTry$2$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(Anorm.scala:303)
    at anorm.SqlResult$class.fold(SqlResult.scala:23)
    at anorm.Error.fold(SqlResult.scala:31)
    at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$asTry$2.apply(Anorm.scala:303)
    at anorm.Sql$$anonfun$asTry$2.apply(Anorm.scala:303)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)
    at anorm.Sql$.asTry(Anorm.scala:303)
    at anorm.WithResult$class.as(SqlResult.scala:120)
    at anorm.SimpleSql.as(SimpleSql.scala:6)
    at com.company.test.user.service.testUserService$$anonfun$findByEmail$1.apply(testUserService.scala:229)
    at com.company.test.user.service.testUserService$$anonfun$findByEmail$1.apply(testUserService.scala:214)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:155)
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:149)
    at play.api.db.DB$.withConnection(DB.scala:61)
    at com.company.test.user.service.testUserService.findByEmail(testUserService.scala:214)
    at com.company.test.controllers.testLoginController.checkPasswordAndSaveUserInSession(testLoginController.scala:128)
```

This is the related code:

```
def findByUserId(userId: Long): TestUser = {
DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  SQL"""
      SELECT s.test_users_id, s.test_users_email AS user_email, s.test_users_first_name, s.test_users_second_name, s.company, s.useas, s.Stripe_CUSTOMER_ID,
  s.is_invoice_customer, s.test_users_invoice_email,
  s.password_hash, s.salt, s.invoice_address,
        s.time_zone, s.last_payment_date AS user_last_payment_date, s.sign_up_date, s.test_role AS user_test_role, s.num_seats, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_users_paid_for WHERE test_users_admin_id = $userId) AS paid_for_seats,
  s.syndication_access_manager, p.test_users_admin_id, pe.last_payment_date AS admin_last_payment_date, pe.test_role AS admin_test_role,
  s.first_payment_date AS first_payment_date, pe.first_payment_date AS admin_first_payment_date, pe.test_users_email AS admin_email, pe.company AS admin_company, s.utm_source, s.utm_medium, s.utm_campaign, s.sf_exec, s.bounced_email,
  s.vat_number

  FROM test_users AS s
  LEFT JOIN test_users_paid_for AS p ON email_users_email = s.test_users_email
  LEFT JOIN test_users AS pe ON p.test_users_admin_id = pe.test_users_id

    WHERE s.test_users_id = $userId
      """.as(simple.single)
}
}

val customer = {
get[Long]("test_users_id") ~
  get[Option[Long]]("test_users_admin_id") ~
  get[String]("company") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("admin_company") ~
  getAliased[Option[DateTime]]("first_payment_date") ~
  getAliased[Option[DateTime]]("admin_first_payment_date") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("user_test_role") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("admin_test_role") map {
  case testUserId ~ testUsersAdminId ~ company ~ adminCompany ~ firstPaymentDate ~ adminFirstPaymentDate ~ testRole ~ admintestRole =>
    if(testUsersAdminId.isDefined){
      getCompanyCustomer(testUsersAdminId, adminCompany, adminFirstPaymentDate, admintestRole)
    } else {
      getCompanyCustomer(Some(testUserId), Some(company), firstPaymentDate, testRole)
    }
}
}

  def getCompanyCustomer(testUsersAdminId: Option[Long], adminCompany: Option[String], adminFirstPaymentDate: Option[DateTime], admintestRole: Option[String]): Option[CompanyCustomer] = {
for {
  id <- testUsersAdminId
  company <- adminCompany
  firstPaymentDate <- adminFirstPaymentDate
  testRole <- admintestRole
} yield CompanyCustomer(id, company, firstPaymentDate, testRole)
}

val simple = {
get[Long]("test_users_id") ~
  getAliased[String]("user_email") ~
  get[String]("test_users_first_name") ~
  get[String]("test_users_second_name") ~
  get[String]("company") ~
  customer ~
  get[String]("useas") ~
  get[Option[String]]("Stripe_CUSTOMER_ID") ~
  get[Boolean]("is_invoice_customer") ~
  get[Option[String]]("test_users_invoice_email") ~
  get[Array[Byte]]("password_hash") ~
  get[Array[Byte]]("salt") ~
  get[String]("invoice_address") ~
  get[Option[String]]("time_zone") ~
  getAliased[DateTime]("user_last_payment_date") ~
  get[DateTime]("sign_up_date") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("user_test_role") ~
  get[Option[Int]]("num_team") ~
  get[Int]("paid_for_team") ~
  get[Option[Long]]("test_users_admin_id") ~
  getAliased[Option[DateTime]]("admin_last_payment_date") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("admin_test_role") ~
  getAliased[Option[DateTime]]("first_payment_date") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("admin_email") ~
  getAliased[Option[DateTime]]("admin_first_payment_date") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("utm_source") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("utm_medium") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("utm_campaign") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("sf_exec") ~
  get[Option[Long]]("access_manager") ~
  get[Option[String]]("vat_number") ~
  getAliased[Boolean]("bounced_email") map {
  case testUsersId ~ userEmail ~ testUsersFirstName ~ testUsersSecondName
    ~ company ~ adminCustomer ~ useAs ~ stripeCustomerId ~ isInvoiceCustomer ~ secondContactEmail ~ passwordHash ~ salt ~
    invoiceAddress ~ timeZone ~ lastPaymentDate ~ signUpDate ~ testRole ~ numteam ~ paidForteam ~ testUsersAdminId ~ adminLastPaymentDate ~ admintestRole ~ firstPaymentDate ~
    adminEmail ~ adminFirstPaymentDate ~ utmSource ~ utmMedium ~ utmCampaign ~ sfExec ~ syndicationAccessManagerId ~ vatNumber ~ bouncedEmail =>
    testUser(testUsersId, userEmail, testUsersFirstName,
      testUsersSecondName, company, adminCustomer, useAs, invoiceAddress,
      stripeCustomerId,
      isInvoiceCustomer,
      secondContactEmail,
      passwordHash.toVector, salt.toVector,
      teamLastPaymentDate(lastPaymentDate, adminLastPaymentDate, testUsersAdminId, stripeCustomerId), new DateTime(signUpDate, DateTimeZone.UTC),
      testRoleFromTeam(testRole, testUsersAdminId, stripeCustomerId, admintestRole), paidByOtherUser(testUsersAdminId, stripeCustomerId), numteam.getOrElse[Int](0), //
      getSeatCount(paidForteam), timeZone.flatMap(getSafeTimeZone),
      firstPaymentDateFromTeam(testUsersAdminId, stripeCustomerId, firstPaymentDate, adminFirstPaymentDate), adminEmail, utmSource, utmMedium, utmCampaign,
      sfExec, syndicationAccessManagerId, vatNumber, bouncedEmail)
}
}
```

Comment: There are 2 `company` columns in your projection (`s`,`pe`).Only use alias in this case. P.S:`getAlias` is deprecated.

Comment: @cchantep We're running on Anorm 2.4.0 at the minute, there's an issue with getAliased in 2.5 preventing us from upgrading. We're waiting for 2.6 to be released to upgrade, so are stuck using getAliased right now. Do you know when we're likely to see 2.6 released?

Comment: `getAliased` should no longer be used

Comment: @cchantep The preventing us from upgrading is with 'get' not 'getAliased'. https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/2.4.x/core/src/main/scala/anorm/Row.scala#L128 vs https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/anorm/Row.scala#L128 Which was fixed in this commit: https://github.com/playframework/anorm/commit/afbbdabf159bf4167883ac9eec621a9860948e24 Where we need both columns returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my problem here was to change all the Aliases to Upper case. This now works fine for me using Anorm 2.4

My new code is below, it also includes some refactoring, but is mostly the same.

```
val simple = {
get[Long]("test_users_id") ~
  getAliased[String]("USER_EMAIL") ~
  get[String]("test_users_first_name") ~
  get[String]("test_users_second_name") ~
  getAliased[String]("USER_COMPANY") ~
  get[String]("useas") ~
  get[Option[String]]("Stripe_CUSTOMER_ID") ~
  get[Boolean]("is_invoice_customer") ~
  get[Option[String]]("test_users_invoice_email") ~
  get[Array[Byte]]("password_hash") ~
  get[Array[Byte]]("salt") ~
  get[String]("invoice_address") ~
  get[Option[String]]("time_zone") ~
  getAliased[DateTime]("USER_LAST_PAYMENT_DATE") ~
  get[DateTime]("sign_up_date") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("USER_SPIKE_ROLE") ~
  get[Option[Int]]("num_team") ~
  get[Int]("paid_for_team") ~
  get[Option[Long]]("test_users_admin_id") ~
  getAliased[Option[DateTime]]("ADMIN_LAST_PAYMENT_DATE") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("ADMIN_SPIKE_ROLE") ~
  getAliased[Option[DateTime]]("FIRST_PAYMENT_DATE") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("ADMIN_EMAIL") ~
  getAliased[Option[DateTime]]("ADMIN_FIRST_PAYMENT_DATE") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("utm_source") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("utm_medium") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("utm_campaign") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("sf_exec") ~
  get[Option[Long]]("syndication_access_manager") ~
  get[Option[String]]("vat_number") ~
  get[Boolean]("bounced_email") ~
  getAliased[Option[String]]("ADMIN_COMPANY") map {
  case testUsersId ~ userEmail ~ testUsersFirstName ~ testUsersSecondName
    ~ company ~ useAs ~ stripeCustomerId ~ isInvoiceCustomer ~ xeroContactEmail ~ passwordHash ~ salt ~
    invoiceAddress ~ timeZone ~ lastPaymentDate ~ signUpDate ~ testRole ~ numTeam ~ paidForTeam ~ testUsersAdminId ~ adminLastPaymentDate ~ adminTestRole ~ firstPaymentDate ~
    adminEmail ~ adminFirstPaymentDate ~ utmSource ~ utmMedium ~ utmCampaign ~ sfExec ~ syndicationAccessManagerId ~ vatNumber ~ bouncedEmail ~ adminCompany =>
    TestUser(testUsersId, userEmail, testUsersFirstName,
      testUsersSecondName, company, useAs, invoiceAddress,
      stripeCustomerId,
      isInvoiceCustomer,
      xeroContactEmail,
      passwordHash.toVector, salt.toVector,
      teamLastPaymentDate(lastPaymentDate, adminLastPaymentDate, testUsersAdminId, stripeCustomerId), new DateTime(signUpDate, DateTimeZone.UTC),
      testRoleFromTeam(testRole, testUsersAdminId, stripeCustomerId, adminTestRole), paidByOtherUser(testUsersAdminId, stripeCustomerId), numTeam.getOrElse[Int](0), //
      getSeatCount(paidForTeam), timeZone.flatMap(getSafeTimeZone),
      firstPaymentDateFromTeam(testUsersAdminId, stripeCustomerId, firstPaymentDate, adminFirstPaymentDate), adminEmail, utmSource, utmMedium, utmCampaign,
      sfExec, syndicationAccessManagerId, vatNumber, getCompanyCustomer(testUsersAdminId, adminCompany, adminFirstPaymentDate, adminTestRole, testUsersId, company, firstPaymentDate, testRole), bouncedEmail)
}
  }

   def createCompanyCustomer(testUsersAdminId: Option[Long], adminCompany: Option[String], adminFirstPaymentDate: Option[DateTime], adminTestRole: Option[String]): Option[NewsWhipCustomer] = {
for {
  id <- testUsersAdminId
  company <- adminCompany
  firstPaymentDate <- adminFirstPaymentDate
  testRole <- adminTestRole
} yield NewsWhipCustomer(id, company, firstPaymentDate, testRole)
}

def getCompanyCustomer(testUsersAdminId: Option[Long], adminCompany: Option[String], adminFirstPaymentDate: Option[DateTime], adminTestRole: Option[String], testUserId: Long, company: String, firstPaymentDate: Option[DateTime], testRole: Option[String]): Option[NewsWhipCustomer] = {
if (testUsersAdminId.isDefined) {
  createCompanyCustomer(testUsersAdminId, adminCompany, adminFirstPaymentDate, adminTestRole)
} else {
  createCompanyCustomer(Some(testUserId), Some(company), firstPaymentDate, testRole)
}
}


def findByUserId(userId: Long): TestUser = {
DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
  SQL"""
      SELECT s.test_users_id, s.test_users_email AS USER_EMAIL, s.test_users_first_name, s.test_users_second_name, s.company AS USER_COMPANY, s.useas, s.Stripe_CUSTOMER_ID,
  s.is_invoice_customer, s.test_users_invoice_email,
  s.password_hash, s.salt, s.invoice_address,
        s.time_zone, s.last_payment_date AS USER_LAST_PAYMENT_DATE, s.sign_up_date, s.test_role AS USER_SPIKE_ROLE, s.num_team, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_users_paid_for WHERE test_users_admin_id = $userId) AS paid_for_team,
  s.syndication_access_manager, p.test_users_admin_id, pe.last_payment_date AS ADMIN_LAST_PAYMENT_DATE, pe.test_role AS ADMIN_SPIKE_ROLE,
  s.FIRST_PAYMENT_DATE AS FIRST_PAYMENT_DATE, pe.FIRST_PAYMENT_DATE AS ADMIN_FIRST_PAYMENT_DATE, pe.test_users_email AS ADMIN_EMAIL, s.utm_source, s.utm_medium, s.utm_campaign, s.sf_exec, s.bounced_email,
  s.vat_number, pe.company AS ADMIN_COMPANY

  FROM test_users AS s
  LEFT JOIN test_users_paid_for AS p ON email_users_email = s.test_users_email
  LEFT JOIN test_users AS pe ON p.test_users_admin_id = pe.test_users_id

    WHERE s.test_users_id = $userId
      """.as(simple.single)
}
}
```

Comment: Once I got this working I attempted to upgrade to Anorm 2.5 and changed the getAliased to get. I got this exception: An exception or error caused a run to abort: ColumnName(test_users.test_users_email,Some(USER_EMAIL)) 
anorm.AnormException: ColumnName(test_users.test_users_email,Some(USER_EMAIL))

Comment: The case of the meta is choosen by the driver. If the driver exposes in all uppercase, then Anorm doesn't change that.

Comment: So, in `anorm` v. `2.5.2`, should this issue still persist? Also, am I correct in understanding that this SO question's issue was that the `SqlParser` tried to read an alias in lower-case, rather than upper-case? In short, using upper-case to retrieve an alias fixed the problem?

Comment: Hey @KevinMeredith, I believe cchantep kindly push this fix out for me in the `2.5.1` release, so the issue should be resolved in `2.5.2`. But yes, using upper case for aliases resolved my initial problem